# Cannot load angular2 app correctly on Plunker

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, plunker

**[Plunker 1](http://plnkr.co/edit/RXgPsKvTf91d2dkltcb4?p=preview)** fails with the following error:

```
zone.js:323 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://run.plnkr.co/XaKTrrlcPIlCBySj/node_modules/rxjs/index.js(…)
```

**[Plunker 2](https://plnkr.co/edit/8NRjj2ylo1WTjTRMIgZA?p=preview)** fails with this other error:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined(…)
```

I'm stuck and with no idea on how to proceed... anyone can help?

Comment: You can just use the menu New > Angularjs 2.0.x (TS) to get a working Angular2 Plunker template.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I think that Plunker 2 already uses that template... still no success in making it run.... any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting HTTP 404 error which

```
The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code, in computer network communications, to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

The web site hosting server will typically generate a "404 Not Found" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link; hence the 404 error is one of the most recognizable errors encountered on the World Wide Web.
```

So basically server is not able to locate resource "http: //run.plnkr.co/XaKTrrlcPIlCBySj/node_modules/rxjs/index.js".

Since its response code return by server, client can not resolve this error.

Regards,
Sudhansu

Comment: rxjs is included in the bundle.js, however it seems that a something like a require('node_modules/rxjs/index.js') is issued somewhere... not understanding where.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this configuration instead for SystemJS for example:

```
map: {
  app: "./src",
  '@angular': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular',
  'rxjs': 'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6'
},
```

because you don't have `node_modules` folder in your plunkr...

See this plunkr as a sample: https://plnkr.co/edit/Qdm8GFsD5Rh1ioJV6jQM?p=info.

Here is a template for RC versions provided by the Angular team: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue.

Comment: I started from this [template](http://plnkr.co/edit/o077B6uEiiIgkC0S06dd?p=info). @angular/rxjs are contained in [bundle.js](https://angular-code.firebaseapp.com/bundle.js) loaded by index.html.

Comment: I used also your template but I get a bunch of errors. [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8NRjj2ylo1WTjTRMIgZA?p=preview)

Comment: Really? Perhaps you could use the template for RC versions provided by the Angular team when creating an issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue.

Comment: I looked at it, and it seems to me really the same of Plunker 2 sample. I am quite convinced that @angular RC with RxJS (latest) doesn't run correctly on Plunker with transpiling...

Comment: The difference is at the level of the `map` entry of the SystemJS configuration...